# Convert Spark Streaming Data frame to Regular Data frame using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am new to spark-ml, trying to convert spark-streaming to regular spark-data frame and the other way round too. I have read the datasets in both ways now I want to go back and forth. Anyone there please guide me.